# Como mudar data-start-height do html por Media Queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, height

Tenho um [site](http://pousadamonteiro.com.br) baseado em um template que comprei no themeforrest, o banner da página inicial desse site tem sua altura ajustada por esse atributo: data-start-height (que eu  nunca havia usado, conheço html e css intermediariamente). Gostaria de mudar esse atributo conforme o dispositivo do usuário por media queries, sei mudar o height css padrão, mas não gostaria de mexer na estrutura html do site então queria saber se é possível modificar esse o data-start-height por media queries ou outra solução parecida.

```html
<section class="main-slider" data-start-height="550" data-slide-overlay="yes">
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode tentar:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 800){  
        $(".main-slider").attr("data-start-height", 500);
    }else if($(window).width() <= 600){
        $(".main-slider").attr("data-start-height", 350);
    }
    // ...
});
```

O `$(window).resize(function(){...}` executa quando a página e redimensionada.

Com `$(window).width()` você pega o tamanho da tela `width` e verifica se for menor que 600px, 500px, 800px...

E de acordo com os tamanhos de tela você define um valor para `data-start-height` com:

```
$(".main-slider").attr("data-start-height", 500);
```